# Rasa: Replace agent with another agent

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, rasa

I am using the Rasa framework for my chatbot. I am storing the metadata during the chat using `trackerstore`.

When the user leaves the chat in between and comes back after some time, I want to restart rasa, and recreate the agent and update it based on the data stored.

I am able to recreate the agent based on the data stored. Is there any way to replace this newly created agent with the already existing agent in the Rasa application server? Or is there a way to respawn another server application with this new agent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can restart your agent at any time. but automatically it will not restart.

You want to put custom logic inside your actions and place below code when you need to restart it.

Like after 5 minute of idol time or any specific action execution.

```
    from rasa_sdk.events import Restarted
    return [Restarted()]
```

Comment: I want to replace the agent and not restart using an inbuilt event.